# How do I pass two ranges to DateAdd?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I'm developing a script that checks dates based on a time range.

```
POS_DATAPOSICAO BETWEEN @data AND DATEADD(MINUTE,3, @data)
```

In this example I am passing an interval of 3 minutes more.

How do I put 3 minutes more and 3 minutes less on the same DATEADD?

Comment: There is a date_add in mysql and a date_dub but no dateadd?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add have you tagged correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what SQL version you're in, as you didn't say

1. Function in MySQL is not "dateadd()" but "adddate()" which is a synonym for DATE_ADD().
2. Format in MySQL is "@data, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE" rather than "MINUTE, 3, @data"
3. your first paramater just needs to be altered for the start like you altered the second parameter for the end:

   POS_DATAPOSICAO BETWEEN DATE_SUB(@data, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) AND DATE_ADD(@data, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the smaller date as first Argument like so:

```
POS_DATAPOSICAO BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -3, @data) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 3, @data)
```

I think this might solve your problem. You can find further information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add